# idle_in_transaction_session_timeout on query COMMIT and ROLLBACK

Tags: postgresql

i've set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in my db postgreSQL for 600000 (10 mins) it works like a charm for SELECT query but then i check there are a few queries that idle for over 35 mins but still not cut from the idle connection, is there any exception for query COMMIT and ROLLBACK? because if these queries are stuck with so many records it will cause a spike in our db usage

i want all queries that idle for over 10 mins will be terminated without exception.. is there a way? thank you

Comment: `idle` is something different than `idle in transaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` my definition only terminates sessions that are idle, but in a transaction. If a session has run `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, it may be idle, but it is certainly not in a transaction.

From PostgreSQL v14 on, you can use the parameter `idle_session_timeout` for that.

However, I believe that you may be tackling a problem at the wrong end: if your problem is that an application keeps opening new connections, but never closing or reusing them (a connection leak), you should fix the application code.

---

Your comments make clear that you think that an entry in `pg_stat_activity` where `qoery = 'COMMIT'` and `state = 'idle'` is a problem. Yet `query` is not only the currently running query, but also (if the session is idle) the *last statement that was run in that session*. So I'd say that the best thing you can do is to stop worrying and to leave the configuration as it is.

Comment: so if i want all query that idle for > 10 mins terminated i should use idle_session_timeout instead idle_in_transaction_session_timeout right? because if these queries (commit & rollback) are stuck with so many records it will cause a spike in our db usage

Comment: @FahmiRoihan: how do you know those queries are "stuck"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my apologize, i think it's not stuck but takes time too long..

Comment: @FahmiRoihan: how do you know it "takes too long"?

Comment: because it's idle for more than 30 minutes @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @FahmiRoihan If it's "idle" it's not doing anything.

Comment: i see, so it's ok/safe if we terminate the "idle" query that run COMMIT or ROLLBACK right? @a_horse_with_no_name